# How redirect the "no-route" cms page to home page after 10 second (not through server side)

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, 404-page, cms-pages

How would be possible using js (in admin,cms-page) to **redirect** the **404 page** to **home page**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add set `setTimeout`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function scr(){

  window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
 }

  setTimeout(scr,10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you enhance the code and alter the way you specified the url?

Comment: @Zinat gopal patel already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Edit in @Qaisar Satti's Ans

put this script in no-route cms page content

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function scr(){
      window.location = "{{store url=""}}";
    }

    setTimeout(scr,10000);  

</script>
```

Comment: why added the jQuery?

Comment: Upppps have habit to add jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in head.phtml file

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()=="no-route"): ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=<?php echo $this->getUrl();?>" />
<?php endif;?>
```

You can make a seperate phtml file for this and add this block file using xml